# Install Debian stable linux ISO from USB to dual boot Windows

Tags: windows-vista, installation, partitioning, debian, multi-boot

I want debian as dual boot with  my windows vista, Free'd up 50GB in my d drive. Plan to use 40 for debian install, 6GB for swap space

Have a 16GB USB drive

Downloaded http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Downloaded DVD files of stable debian-7.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso ( debian-7.0.0-amd64-DVD-2.iso and 3)

After I choose HD install, unetbootin says place the ISO in the same place. but I have 3. do i need to merge them? if so any freeware to do that? can i do it with 7zip? when I extract with 7 zip there are classes between the 3 ISO files. Just over write? Options to merge (format etc for 7zip) ?  Or I must use

I tried to keep the 3 files with  the other unetbootin files but get an error msg
Files I have on my USB

```
06/30/2013  11:44 PM         2,835,648 ubnkern
06/05/2013  12:14 AM     3,998,007,296 debian-7.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
06/04/2013  03:30 PM     4,696,872,960 debian-7.0.0-amd64-DVD-2.iso
06/05/2013  01:25 AM     4,698,955,776 debian-7.0.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso
06/30/2013  11:45 PM         6,530,278 ubninit
06/30/2013  11:46 PM               155 syslinux.cfg
06/30/2013  11:46 PM            60,928 menu.c32
```

also i can only copy above files if i format my USB as NTFS

On FAT32 says too large to copy .iso

How do I get around that? My internet needs a login so cannot do net install

Comment: Alternatively, if you have a fast internet connection, you can use the [netinst images](http://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst#smallcd), which allow you to choose what software to install during the installation of the OS itself.

Comment: no my net needs a login so does not work. tried that

Comment: Related: [How to install CentOS 5.5?](http://superuser.com/questions/365725/how-to-install-centos-5-5), [Creating a bootable USB drive from a distro split over two DVD ISOs](http://superuser.com/questions/612314/creating-a-bootable-usb-drive-from-a-distro-split-over-two-dvd-isos)

Comment: i have started downloadint the cd image. lets hope it works. but i cannot understand why when i have the first iso disk the installer does not even start. does it check for part 2 and 3?

Comment: @Karan cd did it. i had read that yesterday too but could not understand why the boot process was not starting. the error message was pretty generic. i was expecting it to start and then let me know that it does not have all the install files (i had palced the first dvd) anyway it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CD was the answer once I had the 16GB USB. Downloaded the CD images from debian using torrent. Wish the site had a rss of the 7 files.

Installation itself was pretty simple, after reading and planning on disk partition. I write this in Iceweasel from Debian (firefox repacked) :-)